# How to compile header, implementation, driver files

Tags: c++, compilation

I have three files: `movie.h` (header); `movie.cpp` (implementation file); `lab9.cpp` (driver file using movie class)

I was given this sample on how to generate a makefile to compile the above files:

http://sci.tamucc.edu/~ptedford/1436Spr12/1436CommonFiles/MakeFileExample.txt

However, I'm still having trouble grasping the concept here (I don't even know where to fill in my filenames because the sample file names confuse me (such as: what is main.o supposed to represent here?)).

Can someone help me make sense of this (a solution with an explanation), such that it produces a single executable called `lab9`?

Edit: I have the following in my makefile:

```
linkAndRun: lab9.o movie.o
        g++ movie.o lab9.o -o lab9

movie.o: movie.cpp movie.h
        g++ -c movie.cpp -o movie.o

lab9.o: lab9.cpp
        g++ -c lab9.cpp -o lab9.o
```

I'm getting several compile errors, but the compile itself seems successful. Is this correct? The two answers provided so far both had differences, so I combined what I **felt** was the correct things. So confirmation would help though.

Comment: Erm, take your filenames, replace the ones in the example. Done.

Comment: Does one of those files have a definition of `main()` in it?

Comment: @BrianRoach I understand your mindset, and you'd have every right to call me out on what may be a pretty stupid question, but regardless...I'm confused. In particular I don't get the use of the subfile1 and subfile2 compile statements. It seems like one of them isn't needed.

Comment: Well, you only have 2 files to compile rather than 3 so yes, you wouldn't have 3.

Comment: If the build is successful, it's not errors you have but _warnings_. They are not fatal, but can tell you about things that _might_ be wrong and may cause trouble in the future. It's always a good idea to try and fix warnings.

Comment: Also, we can't really tell whats wrong without seeing the errors/warnings you have. Can you please add them to the question?

Comment: It's such a charm coming back to questions like these. Makes me realize how far I've come. Too bad the link is broken now...I don't remember what it had exactly. Sorry, viewers. Check the selected answer and you have a very good idea where to start :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for-

```
executeThis: lab9.o movie.o 
    g++ lab9.o movie.o -o lab9

lab9.o: lab9.cpp
    g++ -c lab9.cpp -o lab.o

movie.o: movie.cpp movie.h
    g++ -c movie.cpp -o movie.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(this step links the object files together and generates your executable)

```
linkAndRun: movie.o lab9.o                 
   g++ movie.o lab9.o -o run
```

(this step compiles movie.cpp to an object file)

```
movie.o: movie.cpp 
   g++ -c movie.cpp -o movie.o
```

(this step compiles lab9.cpp to an object file)

```
lab9.o: lab9.cpp
   g++ -c lab9.cpp -o lab9.o
```

I just substituted your files into the example, excluding the header files

Comment: What purpose does the first variable name (linkAndRun) serve? It seems as though it doesn't matter what it is, but I'm interested in the purpose. Also, I would assume `lab9` can replace `run`, right? Otherwise, this helps explain things. It confirms my suspicion that there were too many compile statements in the example. That's what was throwing me way off.

Comment: The example used three cpp files, you only have two. That is why the number was 'off'. The name of the first section doesn't mean anything, it can be anything you want. Similarly, run can be replaced by anything that you want.

Comment: Doesn't the second compile statement need `movie.h` after `movie.cpp`? Also, linkAndRun: should include the two previously compiled files, right? Wouldn't that be lab9.o and movie.o as shown in my most recent edit?